# Aschroder_SMTPPro - need this one for magento 2

Tags: extensions, email, smtp, hyva, hyva-themesmagento2-default-theme

i want Aschroder_SMTPPro for magento 2 and wants to know weather it will be hyva compactible or not?

Comment: Upgrade to Magento 2.4.6, you wouldn't even need an SMTP 3rd party module since it's now available in the core modules. Also, as in the other answers, Hyva doesn't override emails.

Answer (score 0):

> `Aschroder_SMTPPro` magento extension is available only for Magento
> 1.x platform not for Magento 2.x .
>
> Secondly `Hyva` is a drop-in replacement for Magento 2 / Adobe Commerce
> store front default LUMA theme (which has really improved the store front performance for its vendors) and has no dependency with Email functionality, so any SMTP magento2 extension will
> work with Hyva by default.

Some free Magento2 SMTP modules are given below

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

https://www.aitoc.com/magento-2-smtp.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

**The above module is available for Magento 1, not for Magento 2. This module is used to enable SMTP for Magento to send emails. So, why do you need this module for Magento 2? Also, this is a backend module, and it does not have a frontend interface, so don't worry about it. There are many free modules on Google that provide the same features and functions for Magento 2.**

**Free Module Links:**

1. Mageplaza SMTP for Magento 2 : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/
2. Magefan SMTP Extension for Magento 2 : https://magefan.com/magento-2-smtp-extension

And many more on the Magento Marketplace.